# Does an element exist in or is a subset of another set if that other set has an element which is a set, the same set as the first set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am really confused about having sets in sets and explaining whether some other set exists in vs. is a subset of that set. Example:

$$
A = {\{\{1\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}}\\
B = {\{1\}}\\
C = {\{\{1\}\}}\\
D = {\{\{2\}\}}\\
E = {\{\{2, 3\}\}}\\
F = 3
$$

My guess would be that
$$
B \notin A\\
C \subset A, C \subseteq A, C \in A \\
D \notin A \\
E \notin A \\
F \notin A
$$

Am I correct about my guess? If so, why does the set $B = \{1\}$ "not exist in" A when clearly the element 1 exists in A?

Is there a difference between B and F in that one is a set and another is just a number, or is F also expressed as a set in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The only guesses you got wrong were: $B \not\in A$ and $C \in A$.

$\bullet$ $B \in A$ because, B is an element of $A$.

$\bullet$ $C \not\in A$ because, C is not an element of $A$.

$B$ is a set while, $F$ is number. Sets can be elements of other sets, just as numbers can. There's actually some standard hierarchical language designated for sets whose elements are all sets, and so on. But you could also have a variety of different mathematical objects as elements of a set.

Answer (score 1):

We do not say that P exists (or not) in  the set Q. we say P is (or is not) a member of Q, equivalently that P belongs to (or doesn't belong to) Q.

When we write $A=\{....\}$ we mean that the members of $A$ are all those, and only those, things that are named or defined or satisfy some property specified by the "....".

So $A=\{\{1\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ means that $\{1\}\in A$ and $\{1,2,3\}\in A$ and nothing else is a member of $A.$ Since one of these members, namely $\{1\},$ is $B,$ we have $B\in A.$

The set $C=\{\{1\}\}$ has exactly one member, and that member is the set $\{1\}.$ Neither of the members of $A$ is a set whose sole member is the set $\{1\};$ one of them, $\{1,2,3\}$ has more than one member, while the other one, $B,$ does not have $\{1\}$ as a member : It has "$1$" as a member. However, $C$ is a subset of $A$ because there is no member of $C$ that does not also belong to $A.$

The relation $\in$ is not automatically transitive: $P\in Q\land Q\in R$ does not guarantee that $P\in R.$